How can I create/generate a playlist with cloudfare stream?
I have developed a platform to send videos via the cloudfare API (stream) and then broadcast the videos 24/7. Is there a way to create a file and generate a m3u8 playlist based on the videos from cloudfare stream? Cloudfare stream provides me with an hls file of each video, but how can I create a complete playlist of several videos in just one file m3u8 for constant reading?
For the moment I just have a playlist of each video in HLS and a js script that switches one to the other when a video ends.


"How can I create a complete playlist of several videos in just one file m3u8 for constant reading?"

M3U8 is just a text file with URLs to video chunks (usually .ts or .m4s files). You will have to add the URLs of next video' chunks right after the last chunk's entry from the first video.
Note: All videos must be encoded to same codec settings (eg: width/height, or profiles if using H.264, etc).
As an example, assuming there are 3 videos and each video is only 3 chunks:
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:12
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:10.000,
https://exapmle.com/vid_01/seg-1.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
https://exapmle.com/vid_01/seg-2.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
https://exapmle.com/vid_01/seg-3.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
https://exapmle.com/vid_02/chunk-1.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
https://exapmle.com/vid_02/chunk-2.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
https://exapmle.com/vid_02/chunk-3.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
https://exapmle.com/vid_03/seg_001.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
https://exapmle.com/vid_03/seg_002.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
https://exapmle.com/vid_03/seg_003.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST

